# Mac Safari DIVs width is bigger than other browers

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem which is only MAC Safari specific. my code looks like

```
<div class="wrapper" style="max-width:1220px">
 <div style="width:50%;display:inline-block">First</div>
 <div style="width:25%;display:inline-block">Second</div>
 <div style="width:25%;display:inline-block">Third</div>
</div>
```

on all browsers it looks good even on Safari under Windows but under Mac the `third` DIV wraps to next line. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show your css? With this piece alone actually all three <div>s should wrap to a new line.

Comment: Sorry, die DIVs have also display:inline-block property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in the comments, your s are displayed as inline-block.
This means your code is actually applied as this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>First</div> <div>Second</div> <div>Third</div>
    <!-- Note that new lines are applied as whitespace -->
</div>
```

25% + 25% + 50% + *whitespace* > 100%

There are a few solutions for this, two of them are either:
Write all your `<div>`s in one line, like this `<div></div><div></div></div>` without a newline

or

just use `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `float` solution gives a ton of clearing problems. Another alternative is to put `font-size:0` on `.wrapper` and reset it on the children to eliminate the whitespace. Usually the *don't write whitespace you don't want to see* approach is best though.

Comment: "a ton of clearing problems" - I differ on this one as you'd just need to add clearing on .wrapper; there are lots of solutions I wouldn't say this approch 'a' is bettern than 'b'. But I get your point.

Comment: No, you would need to add clearing on the element *after* `.wrapper`, because that element will be 0 pixels high as it doesn't contain any elements in the flow.

Comment: I meant as a pseudo-element (.wrapper:after), my bad.

Answer (score 1):

That *should* not look as you want it to in any browser – because you have whitespace between your inline-block elements, that gets condensed to the width of one space character each when displyed.

`50% + 1 space character width + 25% + 1 space character width + 25%` is more than 100%, and therefor it is *to be expected* that the third elements breaks onto a new line.

I recommend reading css-tricks.com’s [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, whitespace is probably causing your issue.

Could you consider flexbox? [Check support at can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodchris/4532f9v8/)

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="one" class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div id="two" class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div id="three" class="flex-item">3</div>
</div>

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  max-width:1220px;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

#one {
  background: pink; width: 50%;
}
#two {
  background: magenta; width: 25%;
}
#three {
  background: orange; width: 25%;
}
```